# vue: this in different scope get same object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue. I saw a demo like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  {{fullname}}
 </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
      firstName: 'first',
      lastName: 'last'
    },
    computed: {
      fullname: {
        get: function(){
          console.log('getter');
          return this.firstName + this.lastName;
        },
        set: function (newValue) {
          console.log('setter：' + newValue);
          let names = newValue.split(' ')
          this.firstName = names[0]
          this.lastName = names[names.length - 1]
        }
      }
    }
  })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As the code shows, there are two sub-function get and set. In my view, the this variables in these two functions should not be same(because they belongs to different scopes). But it works well. Any idea?

Comment: `this` is determined at runtime. It depends on how the function is called.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. Can you explain more in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one very big misunderstanding. `this` has nothing to do with scope. It has to do with binding.

### What is scope

Let's not use CS language and talk in normal words for a minute. Scope determines weather a variable can be accessed or not. In other words, it determines the "globalness" and "localness" of a variable.

So for example:

```
let x = 0;

function foo () {
    let y = 0;
}
```

`x` is in scope both in the global scope and inside `foo()`. `y` on the other hand is only in scope within `foo()` and is unaccessible outside of it.

### What is binding

Binding has nothing to do with scope (from a programmer's perspective)*. Binding determines which object a property belongs to.

For example:

```
foo = {
    a: function () {},
    b: 0
}

bar = Object.create(foo); // create new instance of object foo

foo.a(); // here the function a() is bound to foo
bar.a(); // here the function a() is NOT bound to foo

let x = bar.b; // here we are NOT accessing foo.b!
```

`this` is a mechanism to refer to an object's own binding. It allows you to write `this.a()` instead of `foo.a()` and `bar.a()` when called from within methods belonging to the same object.

So of course it is the same. They are both bound to the same object: `fullname`.

> `*` note: I say form the programmer's point of view because the javascript spec, which is written from a compiler writer's point of view, merges both concepts of scope and binding into something called context (and sometimes called "scope", so yes, in the spec "scope" sometimes does not mean scope, it means binding instead)

Comment: Note that this is not only true in Javascript but all object oriented languages. And yes, in languages like Java and C++ people confuse scope and binding as well calling everything "scope"

Comment: Admittedly it's less confusing in Java which does not allow you to declare variables outside of classes - so in effect Java does not have global scope - which means it does not need scope and only need binding. So calling binding scope is not confusing in Java

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Take this code for example. I'll use [Function#call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to alter the `this` value at runtime.

```js
function test() {
  console.log(this.firstName);
}

test(); // undefined
test.call({ firstName: "Test1" });
```

You see, the `this` value is determined when the function is executed. And this is precisely what Vue would be using too. From the Vue [source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/33e669b22f69a1f9c9147528360fe0bba85534f0/src/core/observer/watcher.js#L106):

```
value = this.getter.call(vm, vm)
```